# Generate all days of a gived monts in row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calendar

i need to generate in automatic and in single row all days of a gived months. For example, if month is October i need:

| ROW | DATE | DAY | NOTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/10/2022 | Saturday | ... |
| 2 | 02/10/2022 | Sunday | ... |
| 3 | 03/10/2022 | Monday | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 30 | 30/10/2022 | Sunday | ... |
| 31 | 31/10/2022 | Monday | ... |

How i can to do it? Some macro?
Thanks very much.

EDIT:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why not use a formula to generate. `=SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,MONTH("October"&1),1),0)),,"10/01/2022")`

Comment: This is too a good solution.

Comment: It work, but if i merge two or more cells of row it not work. I get #EXPANSION. How i can fix it?

Comment: What is `#EXPANSION` error ? This is a dynamic spill array formula, what are you trying to merge can show me a screenshot please

Comment: I have copied your formula in A5 cell and excel generated all correctly. After i merged A5, B5 and C5 in a cell then return #EXPANSION! with error: "expansion interval include merged cell" (translate from italian) and not display nothing.

Comment: Oh now i understand are you trying to merge the cells A5 to A7, you cant do that, as i said above its spill formula, when you try to merge it will give you `#SPILL!` error

Comment: I have mistaked before, not a5, a6, a7 but a5, b5, c5. Yes give me it: #SPILL!.  I asked becouse i have complex scheet from layout is formatted using small cell and merging it for to adapt content to cell.  
No solution for it? Then, some alternative?

Comment: Yes certainly there is. Can you show me one screenshot to understand better and provide a proper solution. what is there in B5 & C5

Comment: Well, you can do something like this, I assume here, the cells B5 & C5 are not having spilled array formulas, `=CONCAT(INDEX(A5,COLUMN(A1)),B5:C5)`

Comment: I have added screenshot in my post. Sorry if i done photo with mobile. I have had some problem with pc.

Comment: Try using this formula `=CONCAT(TEXT(INDEX(A5,COLUMN(A1)),"d/m/yyyy"),B5:C5)`

Comment: Not work. maybe i mistake something. Concat function merge two or more cell ?

Comment: `CONCAT()` can merge upto 32767 characters (cell limit) provided you are using in these version available `Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac Excel for the web Excel 2021 Excel 2021 for Mac Excel 2019 Excel 2019 for Mac Excel 2016 Excel 2016 for Mac`

Comment: Ok, date is just 10 character. Can tell me how i can apply this concat to formula? I tried something as:  CONCAT(TEXT(INDEX(SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,MONTH("October"&1),1),0)),,"10/01/2022"),COLUMN(A1)),"d/m/yyyy"),B5:C5) but not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing as an alternative to **VBA**. Custom formula created using `LAMBDA()`

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `B4`

```
=DATE.SERIES(C2)
```

---

The Excel `LAMBDA()` function gives us a way create custom functions that can be reused throughout a workbook, without using VBA, with a friendly name.

The formula used in **Name Manager** as shown below with testing syntax

```
=LAMBDA(text,
LET(_month,MONTH(text&0),
_firstDay,DATE(2022,_month,1),
_lastDay,EOMONTH(_firstDay,0),
_dates,SEQUENCE(DAY(_lastDay),,_firstDay),
_day,TEXT(_dates,"dddd"),
VSTACK({" DATE","️ DAY"},HSTACK(_dates,_day))))(C2)
```

---

Copy the above formula, not including the testing parameters at the end, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, this opens the **Name Manager**, click **New**.

In the **New Name dialog**, enter the name  "DATE.SERIES", leave the scope set to **workbook**, and paste the formula you copied into the "**Refers to**" input area, press **OK**.

Now that the `LAMBDA()` formula has a name, it can be used in the workbook like any other function. Note since dates are stored as number in Excel, it will show as numbers, therefore you need to format as per your desire date format.

---

Here is a quick gif:

[image]